# How to initialize a RangeSeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar

**I am using:**

https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Where the absolute min and max values are set, but how to set the initial values?

I want to start the seek bar with values **0, 10.**

Also, is there any better way to get a range seek bar? This link is too old.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to set the initial values?

14 seconds' worth of scanning the source code turns up `setSelectedMinValue()` and `setSelectedMaxValue()`.

Comment: Hmm.Sad, I was just searching for some setMin, setMax... methods.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Well, since you have the source code, you can rename `setSelectedMinValue()` and `setSelectedMaxValue()` to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You must use:

```
rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(15, 90);
```